# How to search for a place within specified area in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an area (multiple regions in France) on the map described by geographical coordinates (longitude and latitudes). Is there a way to pass this set of coordinates to google API and limit search results within this area?

We are using the following example from google documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass a special set of coordinates to your `Searchbox`, nor to the `Autocompelte` field.

However, you can limit your result to a *type of area*. All types are defined [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?csw=1#table2). Depending of what you call "regions", you should take a look to restrict your search to
`types: ['(regions)']` or `types: ['(administrative_area_level_{X})']`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `bounds` [SearchBoxOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#SearchBoxOptions) to "bias" the search towards your geographic area.

> google.maps.places.SearchBoxOptions object specification
>
> The options that can be set on a SearchBox object.
>
> Properties
>
> Properties    Type    Description
>
> bounds    LatLngBounds    The area towards which to bias query predictions. Predictions are biased towards, but not restricted to, queries targeting these bounds.

Note that a `LatLngBounds` object is a rectangle, not a polygon.